# updating existing ParseUser properties

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am trying to update an existing property of the current user but it's not registering. Here's my code, where did I go wrong?

```
void SaveUserData ()
{
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
    currentUser["Remaining_lives"] = 1;
    currentUser.SaveASync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put `async` before `void` and `await` before `currentUser.SaveAsync();`
let me know if it works! ;)